# How delete properties of one object that are not in another object

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have two objects like the ones below.

```
let a = {Friday: [1, 2 3], Saturday: [2,4,2], Sunday: [1,4]}
let b = {Friday: [], Saturday: []}
```

I need some sort of way to delete all the key value pairs from `a` that are not in `b`, so the result would be:

```
{Friday: [1, 2 3], Saturday: [2,4,2]}
```

Comment: so you want only sunday?

Comment: No, the opposite, I want Friday and Saturday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use a `for loop` and `delete`:

- Iterate over all the properties in a
- check if the property exist in `b`, if it is not present simply delete the property from `a`.

```js
let a = {Friday: [1, 2, 3], Saturday: [2,4,2], Sunday: [1,4]};
let b = {Friday: [], Saturday: []};

for(let key in a){
  if(!(key in b))
    delete a[key];
}
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

- Get the keys of `b` using `Object.keys`
- Use `reduce()` on that to build an object whose values will be from `a`

```js
let a = {Friday: [1, 2, 3], Saturday: [2,4,2], Sunday: [1,4]};
let b = {Friday: [], Saturday: []}

let res = Object.keys(b).reduce((ac,k) => (ac[k] = a[k],ac),{});

console.log(res)
```

If you are confused with one liner. Below is more easy to understand version.

```
let res = Object.keys(b).reduce((ac,k) => {
   ac[k] = a[a];
   return ac;
},{});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get all keys of `a`, delete from this the ones of `b` and delete the properties of `a` with it.

```js
var a = { Friday: [1, 2, 3], Saturday: [2, 4, 2], Sunday: [1, 4] },
    b = { Friday: [], Saturday: [] };

Object
    .keys(a)
    .filter(k => !(k in b))
    .forEach(Reflect.deleteProperty.bind(null, a));

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is with **for loop** and **if statement**

```
// Removes the pairs from A that are not in B
for (let key in a) if (!b[key]) delete a[key]
```